Is vorticity in ordinary liquids such as water quantized?
In superfluid helium, vortexes are quantized. A whirlpool of superfluid helium contains an integer number of these individual vortex quantas.
But all physics comes from quantum mechanics. So it would make sense that vorticity also is quantized in ordinary liquids such as water. If so, does viscosity and thermal noise drown out these quantum effects and make them impossible to detect?

Water is not a superfluid. It is not all in one quantum state.

Jon said it.  Only vortices in superfluid are quantized.
